# How do I find the voltage across the capacitor?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, circuit-analysis

[image]

The circuit which is shown above has no resistance. So there is no time constant. Plus the current source has no resistance in parallel. So I cant convert it into voltage source. **Is there any way to find the voltage across the capacitor after 6 seconds?**

Comment: [look here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+1%2F6+*+integrate+%282*t++%2B+2%29+for+t+%3D+0+to+t+%3D6)

Comment: oh .. thanks. Didn't think in an easy way :(

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be homework we won't give you a direct answer but guide you through it.

1. First edit your question to write the equation relating capacitance, charge and voltage.
2. Hint: current is the rate of flow of electric charge past a point. What mathematical function can you perform on equation 1 to relate the change in voltage as a function of the current and time?

Edit your post with your work and see if that prompts you enough to complete the task.

Comment: There is no possibility of homework. Because I am not studying in anywhere. I got the answer from the comment. Thanks.

Comment: \begin{equation} i_c = \frac{dv}{dt} \end{equation} I assume that you are asking for this.

Comment: You forgot to add in C making it \$ i_c = C \frac {dv}{dt} \$. I'm glad you figured it out.